# IPv6 multicast interface selection

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6, multicast

The `setsockopt` way to select an interface for the outgoing traffic with IPv4 is `IP_MULTICAST_IF`, which accepts two arguments. From the `ip(4)` manual page:

> Set the local device for a multicast socket.  The argument for
>   `setsockopt(2)` is an `ip_mreqn` or (since Linux 3.5) `ip_mreq`
>   structure similar to `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP`, or an `in_addr` structure.

When trying to do the analogous operation with IPv6 traffic, the option changes to an interface index. From the `ipv6(4)` manual page:

> Set the device for outgoing multicast packets on the socket.
>   This is allowed only for `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_RAW` socket.  The
>   argument is a pointer to an interface index (see `netdevice(7`))
>   in an integer.

What happens in a situation where a network interface (e.g. `eth0`) has multiple addresses assigned to it? Is it the case that IPv6 socket interface has removed the possibility to use each address separately?

Comment: So adding membership is not relevant in case of publishing, which is what the IP_MULTICAST_IF solves in this case. My question is: given an interface with multiple addresses, in IPv4 you are able to publish on a specific address. Given IPv6, this functionality does not appear to be there: why? Is there a way how to get the functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your interface only has one link-local address (`fe80::/10`) and one publicly routeable address, the source address for the outgoing packet depends on the scope of the multicast address you're sending to.

An IPv6 multicast address has the form `ffxy::/16`, where *x* is a flag field and *y* is the scope.  If the scope is 1 (interface local) or 2 (link local), then the source address will be the link-local address.  If the scope is 3 or higher, the source address will be the publicly routeable address.

If on the other hand your interface has more than one publicly routeable address, you need to use `sendmsg` when sending datagrams so that you can set the source address using a `IPV6_PKTINFO` control header.

Below is a full example of how you can do this, assuming you have `2001::1:2:3` and `2002::1:2:3` as IPv6 addresses on one interface and `ff03::1:2:3` is the multicast address you send to.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE   // needed for some IPv6 datatypes to be visible

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

// multicast address to send to
const char *maddr = "ff03::1:2:3";

// uncomment the line for the source address you want to use
const char *srcaddr = "2001::1:2:3";
//const char *srcaddr = "2002::1:2:3";

int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in6 dstaddr;

    struct iovec iovec[1];
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct cmsghdr* cmsg;
    char msg_control[1024];
    char udp_packet[] = "this is a test";
    int cmsg_space;
    struct in6_pktinfo *pktinfo;

    dstaddr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, maddr, &dstaddr.sin6_addr);
    dstaddr.sin6_port = htons(5555);
    dstaddr.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
    dstaddr.sin6_scope_id = 0;

    if ((sock=socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    // set up the msghdr structure with the destination address, 
    // buffer to send, and control info buffer
    iovec[0].iov_base = udp_packet;
    iovec[0].iov_len = strlen(udp_packet);
    msg.msg_name = &dstaddr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dstaddr);
    msg.msg_iov = iovec;
    msg.msg_iovlen = sizeof(iovec) / sizeof(*iovec);
    msg.msg_control = msg_control;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(msg_control);
    msg.msg_flags = 0;

    // add IPV6_PKTINFO control message to specify source address
    cmsg_space = 0;
    cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
    cmsg->cmsg_level = IPPROTO_IPV6;
    cmsg->cmsg_type = IPV6_PKTINFO;
    cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(*pktinfo));
    pktinfo = (struct in6_pktinfo*) CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
    pktinfo->ipi6_ifindex = 0;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, srcaddr, &pktinfo->ipi6_addr);
    cmsg_space += CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(*pktinfo));
    msg.msg_controllen = cmsg_space;

    // send packet
    if (sendmsg(sock, &msg, 0) == -1) {
        perror("send failed");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for! I have some follow-up questions if you don't mind: does this mean that I can skip using `IP6_MULTICAST_IF` altogether and always set this only when emitting a datagram? In which case, is there any performance implication on the kernel, having to reset the route every time something is sent? Another implication is that I can now have a single socket and always just point to a different interface/address, instead of having multiple sockets? Would this work for IPv4 as well?